# PHP Include once to multiple PHP File

Tags: php

I know this sounds like a dumb question, but i want to know if there is a way to include php file once and use it for the rest of the project?

For example

i have a php file which contain my database connection.

```
<?php 
$username = "root";
$db_name = "myDB";
$password = ""; ?>
```

I only want to include it once in my index.php like

```
<?php 
include 'db_con.php';

echo "Content Goes here";

?>
```

then use it for the rest of my project. so in my future PHP file when i

```
echo $db_name;
```

I can just access the variable like a global one.

Is this even possible? or is there any approach or guide I can use to accomplish this trick? Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do so.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve it?

Comment: you can use a router like https://github.com/shanta280/easy_php_router

Comment: Or have a main or "bootstrap" php file which includes that file and then every other file, if your program has one entrypoint and you include the file there, your variables will be accessible throughout the application generally speaking (aside from normal PHP scoping rules)

Comment: Why not just include the DB connection file in the files you need it?

Comment: It's like single import to index.php file then I can use it to the rest of the script.

Comment: Let's say i included the db_con in index.php. when i go to home.php, contact.php. I wouldn't need to include the db_con again, but instead print it directly like a global variable

Comment: You have to include if required. There is no way you can skip.

Comment: Really, if your database connection PHP file is just your credentials, you could just put those strings in an .ini file and then parse it.

Comment: it's just a sample, there is a config.php that i want to include globally without including it repeatedly in every PHP File.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of having stuff done in the background without seeing it. That is why I advice on `include("DB con.php");` it's just one line of code. Use it where you need it and don't use it where you don't need it. That way you don't risk any conflicts or other unforseen problems

Comment: @kiogipaya - can you please clarify the question?  If you include a file in index.php and your other files are called from there, then the initial file you included will behave exactly as you want.  The only potential issue there is variable scope.  If you need those values to be available everywhere you can either `define()` them as constants - or use the design of your application to expose them within classes as needed.  It's really hard to say more without knowing what you are working with

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can use 
`include_once('db_con.php')` or `require_once('db_con.php')`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the configuration, you can transparently add a file for all php requests, with the [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive.

Here is an example with an apache .htaccess:

```
# Prepend the file
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/utilities.php"
```

This will be similar to adding `require '/path/to/utilities.php';` at the start of each main file.